# Facebook classes obsoletes in ParseUI

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform

I'm working on a small project on Android and I decided to integrate Parse because I don't want to spend a lot of time setting up the backend, I also decided authenticate with Facebook, but when I try to add ParseUI to my Android Project it doesn't run because the clases that use ParseLoginFragment.java are obsolete (to be more specific it uses these clases: com.facebook.Request, com.facebook.Response, com.facebook.model.GraphUser). I'm using Android SDK 22, Facebook SDK 4.0.1, Parse SDK 1.9.1 and ParseFacebookUtilsV4-1.9.1)

Does anyone how to fix this?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone get this error too, I just find the solution. The github repository has a branch (currently in development) that supports Facebook SDK 4.

Comment: Shear the link of github repository.